# python3.6: socket.recv() vs socket.recv_into() performance

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, recv

I've been using `python3.6` to capture a high speed udp stream and experimented with both `socket.recv()` and `socket.recv_into()`. I expected `recv_into()` to be faster since it would copy right into a "[preallocated](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/socketmodule.c#L3555)" `bytearray` instead of [creating a new string](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/socketmodule.c#L3512) each time a packet was read and appended to a list.

My test scenario is core bound and I know I am dropping some packets and have a large socket receive buffer size via `setsockopt` on `SO_RCVBUF`. I also shutoff the garbage collector to avoid random interruptions.

The following snippets have similar performance which doesn't make sense to me and was wondering if someone could help point out what I'm missing. Thanks!

```py
pkts = []
while time.time() - t_start < 10.0:
    pkt = s.recv(2048)
    pkts.append(pkt)
num_recv_captured = len(pkts)
```

vs.

```py
buffer = bytearray(2048)

num_recv_into_captured = 0
while time.time() - t_start < 10.0:
    s.recv_into(buffer, 2048)
    num_recv_into_captured += 1
```

Here I am seeing `num_recv_into_captured` to be similar to `num_recv_captured` in a core bound scenario but expected `num_recv_into_captured` to be quite a bit larger.

Answer (score 1):

Performance measurement is very hard. What you see could be due to an issue with your test methodology, or it could be that the results are too close to be noticeable.

So first look at the two methods you're trying to compare. You may assume that the only difference is that the second doesn't need to allocate a new buffer, which is a real difference and the key meaningful one but not the only one. If that was the only difference you would expect it to be reliably faster, but it isn't the only difference. The second method also takes an additional dynamic duck typed argument which Python needs to parse and deal with. This shouldn't take all that much time but it's hard to say how it would compare to the time it takes to allocate 2048 bytes which will be dependent on the methodology the interpreter is using. Python uses a global memory pool and in a tight loop with nothing else going on it is likely deallocating and re-allocating the same memory over and over very quickly without calling any OS functions.

This leads into the next issue that while how expensive those two operations are is hard to determine (maybe someone else knows better just how meaningful either of them is,) they are not quite at the same scale as network communications. You're looking at nano/micro second style differences in performance as they relate to millisecond style network operations. Not only are you calling into the operating system and waiting on IO but in a case where you're receiving data faster than it's being sent your process can very well be put to sleep by the OS especially if you really are core limited. You also mention packet loss which isn't necessarily deterministic.

If you really really care about this scale of performance you should either use C/C++ or Rust or another language that allows you lower level access or write a C/C++ or Cython module and use the C socket library directly with python using that module (if your target platform is linux you can even use recvmmsg to really increase performance). You likely don't though. I don't take issue with experimentation for experimentations sake (I actually find it annoying when you ask such a question and people on the Internet just explain to you why not to bother because you don't need it or whatever,) so if that's the case what you aught to have learned is that often micro optimizations make very little to no difference.

If You are trying to decide which approach to use in a larger project; if you have any reason to prefer one over the other for convenience just use that one. If you are really concerned about performance I'd stick to recv_into. Even if the call isn't any faster than recv. if you have a meaningful application that calls the method its memory characteristics will come into play and I expect the system overall will function better without all of the really small allocations and de-allocations which are unlikely to line up perfectly the way they do in your small benchmarking loop.

edit: just to be clear packet loss isn't deterministic in this instance because the other operations ongoing on your system aren't being logged and duplicated exactly... ie I'd say that it's always deterministic in a theoretical sense but it is effectively unknowable to you as an observer.

edit 2: It suddenly hit me that you mention disabling garbage collecting. This will just disable the collector but reference count based freeing of memory should still happen so it is possible that the tight recv loop is freeing and reallocating the same memory block over and over and since it is being allocated by CPython and not the OS and is a small amount of memory it can likely be done very quickly.

edit 3: it's late... anyway I just noticed that you're adding all the packets to a list under recv so you won't be deallocating and reallocating memory you'll just be leaving them as they are and storing memory addresses in the list structure which should be a very fast operation. Not de-allocating the memory means that you won't get the same addresses re-used but it also means that the de allocation doesn't need to happen and allocating an additional 2048 byte block will still be very quick compared to going to the OS and back to fill the buffer. These operations will also pale in comparison to any OS instituted process sleeps.